# Capturar el id del usuario logueado en javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera capturar el id de mi usuario logueado, mi objetivo es que cada vez que se genera un insert o update se capture el idusuario que ejecuto la operación.

Yo soy nuevo programando pero he estado pensando en algunas soluciones:

1. Yo tengo mi archivo modeloinventario.php y esta pensando que podría capturar el idusuario en una variable y darle el valor al momento de actualizar o insertar un registro.

   ```
   class ModeloInventario
   {
   public function obtenerUnidadxID($nombre)
   {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM unidad WHERE desunidad = '$nombre'";
       $data   = ModeloConexion::ejecutar( $sql , DB_NAME , DB_SELECT );

       return $data['LISTA'][0]->idunidad;
   }

   public function actualizar($post)
   {
       pre($post);
       $obtenerTipoUnida   = $this->obtenerUnidadxID($post['m_idunidad']);

       $sql = "UPDATE inventario SET
           idusuario          =   '".$post['m_idusuario']."',
           idmarca            =   '".$post['m_idmarca']."',
           idtipoplanta       =   '".$post['m_idtipoplanta']."',
           modelo             =   '".$post['m_modelo']."',
           serie              =   '".$post['m_serie']."',
           ubicacion          =   '".$post['m_ubicacion']."',
           sala               =   '".$post['m_sala']."',
           idservicio         =   '".$post['m_idservicio']."',
           idcuadrofuerza     =   '".$post['m_idcuadrofuerza']."',
           idunidad           =   '".$obtenerTipoUnida."',
           capacidad          =   '".$post['m_capacidad']."',
           carga              =   '".$post['m_carga']."',
           factorpotencia     =   '".$post['m_factorpotencia']."',
           eficiencia         =   '".$post['m_eficiencia']."',
           aniofab            =   '".$post['m_aniofabricacion']."',
           anioinst           =   '".$post['m_anioinstalacion']."',
           idestado           =   '".$post['m_idestado']."',
           idsubestado        =   '".$post['m_idsubestado']."',
           observacion        =   '".$post['m_observacion']."'
           WHERE idinventario =   '".$post['m_idinventario']."'
           ";
       pre($sql);
       $data   = ModeloConexion::ejecutar( $sql , DB_NAME , DB_UPDATE );
   }

   ?>
   ```
2. Lo otro seria ir a donde tengo mi formulario: diagrama.php. Para esto debo decir que estoy utilizando el framework www.fancygrid.com y se ejeucta en javascript

Tengo mi session start:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Y tengo un Campo de fancygrid oculto, el código es resumido:

```
<script>
type:'hidden',
name: 'm_idusuario',
id: 'm_idusuario',
value: usuario
</script>
```

Lo que esta pensando es en alguna función que capture el idusuario en la variable usuario.

A continuación pongo mi código de acceso al sistema:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST["usuario"]) &&isset($_POST["password"])){
        if($_POST["usuario"]!=""&&$_POST["password"]!=""){
            //include "conexion.php";
            $obj = new ModeloAcceso();

            $user_id    = null;
            $fullname   = "";
            $usuario    = $_POST['usuario'];
            $password   = md5($_POST['password']);

            $retorno = $obj->validaAcceso($usuario, $password);

            if($retorno['TOTAL'] == 0){
                print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido.\");window.location='../login.php';</script>";
            }else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["user_id"]    = $retorno['LISTA']->idusuario;
                $_SESSION["fullname"]   = $retorno['LISTA']->nombres;
                $_SESSION['start'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60) ;
                //$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
                print "<script>window.location='../inventario.php?menu=inventario';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Si entendi bien, tu ya tienes una variable de sesiòn (user_id) por que no validar si està definiada y al estarlo, la imprimes en un campo de texto oculto para que con JS la puedas tomar?...

Comment: Necesito capturar en una variable mi idusuario del usuario logueado para colocarlo como value: usuario en mi campo usuario que esta oculto.

Comment: Leyendo bien tu comentario la respuesta sería... porque realmente no se como hacerlo. Como lo harías?